# INNO how to use AppModifyPath directive.

Tags: inno-setup

I am looking for a way to un-install previous version of my software. I see that INNO has the  AppModifyPath directive. In testing I do see that this adds a change button when you click on the un-install in the Windows control panel - programs and features.

I have searched the web and seem to find nothing on exactly what this does. I mean it adds the button and when clicked prompts me that my software is not found and do I want to remove it from the control panel - programs and features.

I figure I am being stupid or something... How does one use this exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: It is nothing more than a command line that is executed when you click that button.

Comment: But I think you have found a bug (if I guessed right what you have in your script; next time please include the minimalistic code into your question). I have tried something like this `AppModifyPath="{app}\MyApp.exe" /modify "Whatever"` and into registry was stored `{app}\MyApp.exe" /modify "Whatever` without the outer double quotes (internal constant expanding strips them out for some reason). That leads to the problem you report (because Windows Shell cannot resolve such file name). I'll try to dig deeper into this when I get some time.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. What I really want is to make a rollback to previous version of my app. I know INNO does support this directly so I am thinking that this could be used to call my rollback app on uninstall.

Comment: What rollback are you thinking about ?

Comment: When we upgrade a user to a new version and that version has an issue then the customer can 'rollback' to the previous version and continue to use the product instead of being down. I am coming to the conclusion that maybe a stub installer that download the main installer and then if the customer rolls back just download and re-install the last version.

Comment: There is no such feature in Inno Setup. It would have to store the previously installed files and the overall state of all the setup related stuff somewhere. That's what Inno Setup does not. Besides, this request is out of scope of your question. You have asked how to use the `AppModifyPath` directive for which is the answer, *use it as command line where you can use built-in constants; be aware of the problem with stripping out double quotes*. Except that I think that the change button is used to change installed features rather than rolling back to previous version.

Answer (score 0):

The AppModifyPath  of INNOSETUP is useless to uninstall the application.

Innosetup creates itself an unins000.exe into {app} folder.

The Uninstall feature of the control panel calls this prog that's all.

If your Iss script doesn't unisntall this way means that you have a problem in your script